# How can you update the current relative coordinate in TikZ without adding an element?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to update the current relative coordinate in TikZ without actually adding anything to the picture? For instance,

```
\node at ++(1, 0) (node1) {...};
```

will update the current `x` coordinate by incrementing it by 1, but how can I do this without actually adding a node? Also, it is possible to increment the position within a loop (i.e. to keep the new value between the iterations)?

Comment: you can use `coordinate` if you like. I don't know exactly why you don't want nodes so maybe it is also not good with coordinates. Regarding the iteration question, you can use `\foreach \x [remember=\x as \lastx (initially x0)] in {x1,x2...,xn}{......}`. I hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: You can also use the `grid` path to avoid using a `\foreach` loop. The `x` and `y` steps can be set independently. It would be helpful though, if you gave some information on what exactly you need to increment the coordinate.

Comment: I think we need a little more detail here as to what you are trying to do.  For example, `\path (1,0) ++(2,0) ++(3,0) node {a node};` will work, but may be your actual case is more complicated.

Comment: If you just want to increment the current coordinate, you could try `\path ++(1,0);`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned by others in the comments, you an use `\path` to update the current relative position.  `++(…)` is relative to the last saved position within a particular path, but the start of a path is relative to `(0,0)`. Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {O};% label the origin
\node at ++(1, 0) [orange] {A};% this is relative to (0,0)
\node at ++(2, 0) [green] {B};% still relative to (0,0)
\path ++(2, 0) ++ (1,0) node [blue] {C};% start relative to (0,0), go to (2,0) and then relative to this end up at (3,0)
\path ++(5,0) ++ (1,0) node [red] {D};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The lines starting with `\node at ++(1, 0)` and `\node at ++(2, 0)`, are both relative to `(0,0)`.  The subsequent lines starting with `\path ++(2, 0) ...` starts the path relative to `(0,0)`, and moves to `(2,0)`, and the subsequent `++ (1,0)` is relative to the last point and hence the `C` is placed at `(3,0)`. Note that that nothing was placed at `(2,0)` during this path.

Just to be sure, the last `\path` sets the current coordinate to `(5,0)` and nothing is added to the picture there, only at `(6,0)` do we see `D`.